# Testing UWP app on various inches of desktop

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I want to test my uwp app with various size of windows10 desktop. Mine is 23" Desktop(1920*1080).But even when I select a windows size from appx (for ex : 13.3" Desktop(1280*720)) - the code written below always shows my desktop's resolution.And the design is not changing to selected mode view.How can I test my app in different inches of desktop? Not on mobile devices.

```
 var displayInformation = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView();
 GlobalVraiables.ScreenHeight= (int)displayInformation.ScreenHeightInRawPixels;//1080
 GlobalVraiables.ScreenWidth= (int)displayInformation.ScreenWidthInRawPixels;//1920
```

Comment: You don't really need a multiple sized different desktops to test your app. You can resize your window to check the design. You will have to implement VisualStateManger for this to happen.

Comment: Have you tried using the Visual Studio simulator?